# Not able to detect actual page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage, session-storage

I am using the socket in javascript to emit data. Following is the code snippet.

```
socket.on('my response', function(msg) {
    $('#log').append('<p>Received: ' + msg.data + '</p>');
    /*
    if (window.performance) {
        console.info("window.performance work's fine on this browser");
    } 
    if (performance.navigation.type == 1) {
        console.info( "This page is reloaded" );
    } else {
        console.info( "This page is not reloaded");
    } */
    document.getElementById('div_id').innerHTML += msg.data + "<br>";
});
```

The problem is that the data I am displaying on the div is getting cleared once I reload the page. I want to retain the data and continue appending the data from `msg.data` even after I reload the web page. How can I achieve this? I was trying to detect page reload using the commented part in the above code snippet but it is detecting it as page reload event every time I get the `msg`.

**UPDATE 1**

If detecting reload event and using `session-storage` is the best way then I may have to emphasize on my main issue which is to detect a reload event. It's printing `This page is reloaded` every time I get data in `msg.data`(Using the commented part of the code snippet for detecting page reload event). I want to detect the only manual reloads and `window.location.reload` which I used from other modules of my code.

Comment: you nailed it in your tags, place data in session storage, on document read compare your session storage, with the div's content

Comment: My main problem is in detecting the reload event of the web page. I tried detecting in various ways but as I mentioned in the question it's detecting `my response` events of socket also as a page reload event. How do I avoid this?

Answer (score 2):

Well you could detect a page load event, and then just save the data you got until the page refresh was fired and populate it with the appended afterwards.. for example, but a better thing would be to detect if the document is ready. Because then you dont have to wait for css and images to load as stavm just said.

```
//store data first 
$( document ).ready(function() {
    // your code here
});
```

Comment: i'd use `document.ready`. no point in waiting for CSS, images, and all other assets

Comment: @phanny because sockets.on fires a page reloading event afaik. thats why it gets detected.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine and it can detect what you want.
But javascript variables will clear after reloading the page and it is natural and unavoidable.

You can use HTML5 **loacal storage or Cookies** and each have its own pros and cons.

**Refer following links:**
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Logic :

```
$(function() {
  if(// This page is **not reloaded** ) {
   // **clear** local storage / cookies
  }

  //load / append data to **local storage / cookies**
  //populate data **from local storage / cookies**
});
```

Comment: It's not working as I want it to work. It's displaying `This page is reloaded` every time I get a `msg.data`. I want it to detect only the manual reloads and `window.location.reload()` which I have in various other modules of the code.

Comment: Set a value inside the local storage before call `window.location.reload()`
if it exist when page load, that means your code did it.

Clear the value after loading the page.
If someone refresh the value not be there when the page is loading.

Answer (score 0):

the common way is cache your data. you can cache your msg.data to `localStorage`, when reload, you first try to get data from localStorage, if it has, show it; then, keep socket connection and update.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
function reloadFunction() {
  //set property in local storage;
  window.location.reload();
}

$(function() {
  if( // local storage property exists) {
   // reloaded by code
   // clear local storage property;
  } else {
    // reloaded manually
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

On server side make a var with incremental ID, send it to client. On each reload, compare this var with the one on client side.